# Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\io' Angular 5

Tags: angular

by executing the command `ng test --port 4200`
It receives the following errors:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\io'
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/exec.js 20:21-45
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\net'
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/net/portprober.js 22:15-39
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/zip.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js 24:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/zip.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/sync.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/zip.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\glob'
 @ ./node_modules/glob/glob.js 43:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/zip.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts

ERROR in ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'd:\name_project\node_modules\rimraf'
 @ ./node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/io/zip.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/firefox.js
 @ ./node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js
 @ ./src/app/auth.service.spec.ts
 @ ./src \.spec\.ts$
 @ ./src/test.ts
```

my file **package.json** contains the following libraries:

```
{
  "name": "name-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
    // ..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "karma": "^2.0.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^4.0.0-alpha.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^2.1.3"
  },
  "browser": {
    "fs": false ,
    "child_process": false
  }
}
```

but it did not help. How can I correct errors?

I not have the file `webpack.config.js` only in the catalog `./node_modules/.bin/webpack`

Should I have some libraries to install? Should I set something in chrome browser?

I would be grateful for your help and guidance in solving these errors.